# CollapsingToolbarLayout title not letting into toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout

I have tried the new CollapsingToolbarLayout with toolbar, all went fine, except one thing.

Here's the code `

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="256dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/venue_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/user_header_one"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/finish_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nestedScrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
 .............has linearlyout and it's child
```

`

The problem is when i start to scroll  nestedscrollview, the title under collapspingtoolbar not getting inside the toolbar.

It seems when i click the phone settings and come back to my app the toolbar getting focus and then letting the collapsing title to enter inside the toolbar, this is really weird.

This is under jelly bean 4.1.6

Comment: remove `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"` & `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from `imageView` and `toolbar` resp. Add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to `imageView`

Comment: Nope, that didn't work, still the collapsingtoolbar layout not getting into toolbar

Comment: try this [tutorial](http://blog.grafixartist.com/toolbar-animation-with-android-design-support-library/).

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I was using this inside, Navigation drawers one of fragment, When i remove activity toolbar, and replacing with new toolbar under onResume method, the problem raise. If i attach toolbar inside onCreateView then this works.